# Comparing a String to an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

Right basically what I'm trying to do is a very simple login screen to get to know swing.

My issue is I currently have a file `pass.txt` which is formatted like so:

```
Username = bob,tony,mike
Password = pass,pass2,pass3
```

in my Java file I get the strings by using:

```
String[] user = prop.getProperty("Username").split(",");
```

Now I then compare this with my text input from a `JTextField` however it always fails what I have is:

```
if (input2.equals(pass) && userin.getText().equals(user))
```

Now I'm guessing my issue is I have an array of strings and it's comparing it to a single string now what I want to do is go through the array and if any of them match I want it to take that match and use it if that makes sense, is there any way to go about this?

Comment: You should consider using one of the `Collection` classes available in package `java.util` instead of an array of strings. `Collection` has a `contains` method that can check for the existence of a particular item in the collection.

Answer (score 6):

i think this may help you,because i think you have to check each user with his password int this array:

```
for(int i=0;i < user.size();i++){
  if(input2.equals(pass[i]) && userin.getText().equals(user[i])){
   //your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a `pass` array to match your `user` array, and every entry in `user` is guaranteed to have a corresponding entry in `pass`, then the following solution should work:

```
int index = Arrays.asList(user).indexOf(userin.getText());
String password = pass[index];

if (password.equals(input2)) {
    // Successful authentication
} else {
    // Authentication failed
}
```

- `Arrays.asList(user).indexOf(userin.getText())` will get the index of
  the user in the list (in your example, "bob" => 0; "tony" => 1; "mike" => 2).
- `password` is then the password string at that same index (in your example,
  "pass" => 0; "pass2" =>1; "pass3" => 2).
- Then the if compares the password associated with the user
  (`password`) with the password that was input in the dialog
  (`input2`).

Comment: Some commentary on what this is actually doing: `Arrays.asList(x)` converts an array `x` into a `java.util.List`, with all of the elements of the list appearing in the same order that they appeared in in the array. `indexOf` is a method on `List`, which returns the first index where the given element is found, or `-1` if the given element is not in the list. Note that the above code will actually crash with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the given user name is not in the `user` array, because on line 2 you'd be indexing into the `pass` array with `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to search the username table, find the position of introduced username and then check if the password on that position is equal to what the user introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow search the array for the string you're looking for. There are a bunch of ways of doing this, I'll outline one method.

```
int index = 0;
for (String s : user) {
    if (s.equals(userin.getText()) {
        // the username matches! now check to see if the password at the _same index_ matches
        if (pass[index].eqals(input2.getText()) {
            // correct username and password!
        } else {
            // bad password!
        }
    }
    ++index;
}
```

I'm assuming that you have a password array called `pass` and that the indices match those of the `user` array. (`user[i]`'s password is `pass[i]`)